# PSD of a 100 1kB packets with equally probable 1s and 0s

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density

SO i have to calculate the PSD of mentioned input.

here is my code. (every little thing written wholly and solely by myself)

```
x = 100;  % number of packets of size 1kB
P_final = 0; %final PSD

while(x ~= 1)  % loops over 100 packets
b = rand(1,8192); %1kB packet with equally likely 1s and 0s maaped to -1s and +1s 
                  %with threshold of 0.5
%generating the packet
for n = 1 : 8192
   if(b(n) <= 0.5)
      b(n) = -1;
   else
      b(n) = +1;
   end
end
B = fft(b,8192);      %taking fourier of single packet
Pbb = B.*conj(B);     %calculating PSD
P_final = P_final + Pbb;  %summing all PSDs for averaging later for 100 packets


x = x - 1; %while loop check
end        %end of while loop

P_final = P_final/100;  % averaging PSDs of 100 packets


plot(P_final) %plotting the PSD
title('Power spectral density')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
```

So now the problem is i am getting the output as [image: PSD_incorrect]

But as told in assignment. The output is a sinusoid. which means that its PSD should have one peak and other very small frequency.

I have checked my logic which seems right to me. But i still cant get the output.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT # 1
[image]

Comment: Why do you think you should see a sinusoid? You're estimating the PSD of a white random process, which has a flat density. Your result looks like a noisy constant value, which is what I would expect.

Comment: @JasonR... actually the question was to generate a 1kB packet with equally likely 1s and 0s. and then map them to +1 and -1. since we cant use 0 value. 

Do you think using the rand function is the right choice.??

Comment: Yes, that works fine. A more compact way to do the same thing is `b = 1 - 2 * (randn(1,8192) > 0);`.

Comment: why not `sign(randn(1,8192));`

Comment: @JasonR so i used randn and not i am getting just one frequency component with extremely high amplitude and rest are nearly negligible in comparison. 
Now i cant understand why using a normally distributed random function gives a sinusoid??

Comment: @jan ...so i used randn and not i am getting just one frequency component with extremely high amplitude and rest are nearly negligible in comparison. Now i cant understand why using a normally distributed random function gives a sinusoid??

Comment: i have attached the plot of psd for randn.

Comment: You need to show the code that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
nx = 8192; psd = zeros(nx,1); 
for i = 1:100, x = fft(sign(randn(nx,1))); psd = psd + x.*conj(x); end
plot(10*log10(psd/100/nx));
```

You for equal probability of 1s and 0s (or 1s and -1s) for that matter you would expect the white spectrum to be white, i.e. all frequencies are equally likely. The code snippet above shows this, i.e. all frequencies are close to 0 dB with a little bit of noise on top. The more you average the less noise you will get.

If you have been told that the output is a sinusoid, than there must be some misunderstanding in either the problem or solution statement.